# ng-serve is not working on ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu-17.04

```
ng serve 
You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
```

It gives that error.

```
ls
hello-world  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json

ng -v    

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 9.2.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: undefined
... 

@angular/cli: 1.6.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.1
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

I tried to reinstall npm and cache clean but it did not work.

Some of my commands:

```
 5880  mkdir hello-world
 5881  cd hello-world
 5882  ng new hello-world
 5883  ng serve
 5884  sudo npm install
 5885  ng serve
 5886  ls
 5887  npm init
 5888  ls
 5889  ng serve
 5890  npm install
 5891  ng serve
 5892  npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
 5893  ng serve
 5894  npm install\n
 5895  ng serve
 5896  npm i
 5897  ng serve
 5898  ls
 5899  sudo rm -rf  node_modules
 5900  em package-lock.json
 5901  rm package-lock.json
 5902  npm update
 5903  ng serve
 5904  ls
 5905  npm cache clean 
 5906  sudo npm cache clean 
 5907  sudo npm rebuild
 5908  ng serve
 5909  npm install
 5910  ng serve
 5911  ls
 5912  npm update
 5913  ls
 5914  ng serve
 5915  sudo npm install
 5916  ng serve
 5917  sudo npm update
 5918  ng serve
 5919  ls
 5920  cd
 5921  cd Projects/hello-world/
 5922  ng
 5923  ng -serve
 5924  ng -
 5925  ng -v
 5926  ls
 5927  vi node_modules
 5928  ls
 5929  npm cache clean --force\nnpm cache verify\nnpm i
 5930  ng -serve
 5931  s
 5932  ls
 5933  ng -v
 5934  npm init
 5935  ng -v
 5936  ng -serve
 5937  sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
 5938  sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
 5939  ng serve
 5940  ls
 5941  ng -v
```

I want to install angularcli, angular version 1, but could not manage it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using agular cli to create and serve a project, after editing a file it does not auto update the server & I came across this kind of same issue so have use many command but finally this command works, i have to restart the `ng serve` again.

I tried `ng serve` and `ng build --watch` , both not working

re install npm install , also i checked the folder names but still not working

Or

Execute the following command in your project folder:

```
"npm install --save @1.2.4"
```

and `npm start` or `ng serve`.

For more details:- [angular-cli issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2356)

or

If you are using Ubuntu, You can use `sudo ng serve` or `sudo ng serve --watch`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I've been using Ubuntu I've came to using `sudo ng serve`. That way it does refresh after an update. Looks like without root permissions webpack is unable to watch files.

Comment: @Sergey, i think we can use both sudo ng serve & sudo ng serve --watch
 to refresh the dom elements. & yes thank you for reminding me.. i will update my answer.